# cant login in codeigniter using sessions

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to create a login page, I do not understand where I am going wrong only the second else statement if working

```
else
{
    $username = $this->input->post('username');
    $password = $this->input->post('password');

    $user_id = $this->user_model->login_user($username,$password);

    if($user_id)
    {
        $user_data = array(
                        'user_id' => $user_id,
                        'username' => $username,
                        'logged_in' => true
                        );

        $this->session->set_userdata($user_data);

        $this->session->set_flashdata('login_successful','you are now logged in');


        redirect('home/index');
    }
    else
    {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('login_failure','sorry, not logged in');

        redirect('home/index');
    }
 }
```

Only the last else statement is working and I cant figure out why what am I doing wrong?

Comment: So `if($user_id)` is returning false? Are you able to get an error/warning message?

Comment: see the result of $user_id, maybe login_user is returning an unexpected value

Comment: Do you have a `session_start()`?

Comment: If your `login_failure` is what you see, `$user_id` is falsey, so the obvious things to look at are: a) what is `$user_id`, exactly?  Try `var_dump($user_id);` to check; b) What is `login_user()` doing? Is it receiving the right values?  Is it testing correctly?  Debug it!

Answer (score 0):

Once you already authenticate the inputs to your model it means that all data will pass to the variable `$user_id` if the **user input is correct** and **no need to insert another data** to your variable `$user_data`

```
    $username = $this->input->post('username');
    $password = $this->input->post('password');

    $user_id = $this->user_model->login_user($username,$password);

    if(!empty($user_id)) //check if it was not empty
    {

        $this->session->set_userdata($user_id);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('login_successful','you are now logged in');

        redirect('home/index');
    }else{
          //some code here
         }
```

Comment: the problem was with phpmyadmin, basically what had happened was i had pressed enter to save the data, phpmyadmin saves the enter command as well, i think as a \n and so i had to write \n in the password field